# How to import multiple vue files as one

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

**In other to avoid multiple imports into my vuejs app I created an index.js file and imported all the files in it like so:**

```
import AddMember from "./AddMember.vue";
import EditMember from "./EditMember.vue";

export {
  AddMember,
  EditMember,
};
```

Then in my component compenent I imported them like so:

```
import * as Members from "../members/index.js";
export default {
  name: "members-table",
components: {
    AddMember: Members.AddMember
    EditMember: Members.EditMember,
  },
}
```

The EditMember Component is a dialog that opens up per the member clicked. But Anytime I click on a member on a the table I get and error that looks like this: even though the name prop was defined in all the components.

```
 Unknown custom element: <edit-member> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
```

I resolved the problem my importing the EditMember.vue file itself`import EditMember from './EditMember';`. My question however, is there a way I can achieve this. Or better still what I'm I missing or did wrong.

Comment: I see the error says `edit-member`, are you using `EditMember` in your template or `edit-member`?

Comment: `import Members from ..` then it will work

Comment: The problem might be somewhere else. I've tried various configurations, but seems like it should work. https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-mcclintock-6e4ev

Comment: @Daniel, I used `edit-member`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I tried it. But there were some errors

Comment: @DicksonAfful updated my solution, can you try it?

Answer (score 1):

well if it`s reusable components your trying to do so wouldnt it be better to create base components? and then you dont need to import them each time?
import { AddMember, EditMember } from "../members/index.js"; this should work like @Asimple said

Comment: could also try import a component like this   components: { AddMember, EditMember },

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to import them separately?
Like this:

```js
import { AddMember, EditMember } from "../members";
```

Update:

Changed import source, please, try it.
Working example [here](http://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-turing-uf4px)

Comment: You sure? Export should be without `default`

Comment: Yes it had no default

Comment: It worked for all other components I imported except the `EditMember.vue`. The Idea behind the app is that when a user clicks on the `edit button` on a particular user a dialog opens containing the EditMember Component. I think the problem has to do with the fact multiple `edit buttons`  affect the component (maybe).

Comment: Can you show error and code?
I think it's another problem, not multiple import. So better to create another question and not  make mess here.)

Comment: @DicksonAfful Can you add code with my solution, so i can see whats the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you may need to create alias as:

```
components: {
    'AddMember': Members.AddMember, // use single quotes
    'EditMember': Members.EditMember,
},
```